# Linkeds List using strings

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I get a segfault when I insert into my linked list and I just can't find it. At one point it would allow me to insert up to three nodes but now it segfaults after the first insertion and does not iterate through the while loop and for statements. Am I scanning the information into the array incorrectly? I have to be able to take in several input values because eventually I need to be able to delete and print nodes based on string and count values that will be given by the user.

Input from the user would look like this:

```
ins books
ins table
prl   // to print list
del v1 v5  //to delete nodes with count values that fall between 1 and 5
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

 struct node
{
    char *symbol;// each Node contains a array 'symbol'
    int count; // each Node contains a symbol counter
    struct node *next; 
    };// end struct



void insert(struct node**,struct node **, char *str);
void printL(struct node *);




int main()
{

    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;

    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;


    //Declare variables needed for input and output
    char input[15]={0};
    char cmd [4]={0};
    char info[11] = {0};
    int *val={0};


    //possible command strings
    char ins[]= "ins";
    char prl[]= "prl";
    char end[]= "end";


    // Prompt user for command and corresponding input
    puts("Please enter a command with corresponding value(s) where necessary");
    scanf("%s%s%s", cmd,info, val);


//While command is not 'end':
 while (strcmp(end,cmd) != 0){
         // Read value(s) for the command, in necessary
         if (strcmp(ins,cmd)==0)
         {
            insert(&head, &tail, info);
         }

         if (strcmp(prl, cmd)==0)
         {
            printL(head);
         }


         puts("Please enter your next command and value where necessary:");

        scanf("%s%s%s", cmd,info, val);




    }
    return 0;
}
void insert(struct node **h, struct node **t, char * str)
{

    struct node *temp;

    if ((temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation or node failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(temp->symbol,str);
    temp->count= 1;
    temp->next=NULL;

    if(*h == NULL)
    {
        *h=*t=temp;
    }

    else
    {
    (*t)->next = temp;
    *t = (*t)->next;
    }
}

void printL(struct node *h)
{
   // NodePtr hPtr = NULL;
    //hPtr=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    //hPtr=head;
    if(h == NULL){
        puts("The list is empty");
    }
    else{

        while(h != NULL){
            printf("%s", h->symbol);
            printf("\t %d", h->count);
            h= h->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `val` is not allocated `int` pointer, yet you are trying to `scanf` into it some string...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)))==NULL)
{
    printf("Memory allocation or node failed.\n");
    exit(1);
}
strcpy(temp->symbol,str);
```

You need to allocate memory for `temp->symbol`. The easiest way since you're copying an existing string is to use `strdup` like this instead of doing that `strcpy`

```
temp->symbol=strdup(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to allocate memory for the variable symbol.
Make your insert function as follows:

```
void insert(struct node **h, struct node **t, char * str)
{

struct node *temp;

if ((temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)))==NULL)
{
    printf("Memory allocation or node failed.\n");
    exit(1);
}
int count = 0;
count=strlen(str);
temp->symbol=malloc(count+1);
strcpy(temp->symbol,str);
temp->count= 1;
temp->next=NULL;

if(*h == NULL)
{
    *h=*t=temp;
}

else
{
(*t)->next = temp;
*t = (*t)->next;
}
}
```